# What can be a Good Approach for ETL when data is on SharePoint Online and to be Used for Power BI?

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, powerbi, azure-sql-database

I am working on a case where, we have a large volume of data. All the data is located in different Excel files which are having more than 500000 rows in each file. The files will gets added monthly.

I have created Power BI Report and each Month when the new file gets loaded, it takes a lot of time to refresh.

To make it simpler, we are trying to use SSIS where the data will be imported from the Excel files in to a DB and then the DB will be used as Base Data to the Power BI File.

In this case, we are downloading the data locally from cloud (SharePoint Online) and then again Uploading it to Cloud (to Power BI Premium Workspace.).

Guys, I am not sure whether this is the right approach and efficient way to optimize the Refresh Time. Can any please suggest if is there any better solution available. Perhaps we may have a solution which will consolidate all the data on the cloud only and so no need to download and transfer it it using SSIS.

Regards,

Comment: I would suggest a Logic App to download the SharePoint files to an Azure Blob Storage location, then use Azure Data Factory to read the files then move the data to the database. That keeps it in Azure and no on-prem SSIS needed

Comment: Hello Jon, many thanks for the guidance. I will try that and get back to you with the results

Comment: @AkshayManke what's the result? did you solve it now?